# Rotating text in the Epilog of a plot results in distortion

Tags: plotting, graphics, rotation, text-formatting

I want to rotate text in a plot. When I rotate by 90 degrees, or 180, it's perfectly OK. But if I want to rotate to 60 or 45 degrees, then the text appears distorted (see example below). How can I fix it?

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {
   Rotate[
    Text[Style["hi" // StandardForm // DisplayForm, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20], {2, 80}], 
    90 Degree
   ], 
   Rotate[
    Text[Style["bye", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 12], {1, 20}],
    45 Degree
   ]
 }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Rotate` inside `Text` (or `Inset`), rather than the other way round:

```
Plot[
  x^2, {x, -10, 10},
  Epilog -> Text[Rotate[Style["bye", 20], 45 Degree], {1, 20}]
]
```

[image: correct orientation of text with no stretching]

Comment: Thanks very much, it really helped.

Comment: @lia You are very welcome.